# How to change bordercolor based on value of textbox? using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a textbox which has a red border as default.

when on focus, (:focus) the border turns green.

When there is 1 or more characters in the textbox, the border turns blue (using this js)

```
function CheckText()

{

    var elem = document.getElementById('sendto');

    if(elem)

      {      
      if(elem.value.length != 0)
      elem.style.borderColor = '#3366CC';
      }

}
```

the problem I have is, if I delete all the characters from the box after it has turned blue, it stays blue and does not return to red. the :focus green does not work anymore either after typing in the cell.

Can anyone help?

this is the HTML code for my box:

```
<input id="sendto" name="sendto" type="text" class="sendsubempty" onBlur="CheckText()" value="<? 
  if(!$sendto){ 
  echo"";
  }else{
  echo"$sendto";
  }
  ?>" maxlength="50" />
```

for info: class- sendsubempty has a red border.

I have seperate classes for blue & green borders if its easier to use in the javascript.

Please help :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a more elegant way to achieve this effect:

http://jsfiddle.net/elias94xx/eqKqS/

**HTML**

```
<textarea id="test"></textarea>
```

**CSS**

```
#test { border-color: red; }
#test:focus { border-color: green !important; outline: none; }
```

**JS**

```
document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("keydown", controlBorderColor, false);
document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("keyup", controlBorderColor, false);

function controlBorderColor() {
  if (this.value.length == 0) { this.style.borderColor = "red"; }
  else { this.style.borderColor = "blue"; }
}
```

Comment: 1 more question,

how can I apply that to 3 input boxes on the same page?

Comment: Using jQuery would be the easiest way: `$(".some_input_boxes").on("keydown keyup", controlBorderColor);`, otherwise just register more event listensers.

Comment: ahhh, ok, Im still learning all of this, but its getting much easier.

I understand now.

so just register more event listeners and when the relevant box is in focus/active, it will simply call the function for that box as Ive registered the listener....

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Loris. But it's not completely correct.

```
function CheckText()

{

    var elem = document.getElementById('sendto');

    if(elem)
    {      
      if(elem.value.length === 0)
      {
        elem.style.borderColor="";
      }
      else{
        elem.style.borderColor="#3366CC";
      }
    }

}
```

Here is the jsbin :
http://jsbin.com/welcome/70238/edit

Comment: Brilliant. much easier.

I have 3 boxes (username, password & message)

I have added 3 versions of the code and simply changed the function name. Is there an easier way to pass the ID as a parameter to the one function? rather than 3 instances of the function code?

Answer (score 0):

The function CheckText should be changed from:

```
  {      
      if(elem.value.length == 0)
      elem.style.borderColor = '#3366CC';
  }
```

to:

```
  {
    if(elem.value.length){ elem.style.borderColor=""; }
    else{ elem.style.borderColor="#36c"; }
  }
```

Comment: This is because inline style has higher specificity than external rule