# Change border color if the field has a value

Tags: javascript

I want to change the border color of the input depending if there is a value or not. I don't understand why the condition is not working. Isn't it checking if the field is empty and should go in the `else` part if something is entered in the input ?

```js
class Validation
{
 constructor(field, noticeMessage) {
  this.field        = field;
  this.noticeMessage   = noticeMessage;
 }

 valid() {
  console.log('coucou');
  this.field.style.borderColor     = "green";
  this.noticeMessage.style.display = "none"; 
  return true;
 }

 invalid() {
  this.field.style.borderColor   = "red";
  this.field.focus();
  this.noticeMessage.style.display = "block";
  return false; 
 }

 empty() {
  if (this.field.value == "") {
   this.invalid();
  }
  else {
   this.valid();
  }
 }
}

const titleValidation = new Validation(document.getElementById('name'), document.getElementById('name-notice'));
titleValidation.empty();
```

```html
<div class="notice">
 <ul>
  <li id="name-notice">The name input must be filled</li>
 </ul>
</div>

<form>
 <label>name</label>
 <input id="name" type="text" name="name">
</form>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change bordercolor based on value of textbox? using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14183794/how-to-change-bordercolor-based-on-value-of-textbox-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to validate once when the program gets loaded, but you want to update whenever the input changes. You can do that by attaching an event listener to the input event:

```
constructor(field, noticeMessage) {
    this.field           = field;
    this.noticeMessage   = noticeMessage;

   this.field.addEventListener("input", () => this.empty());
   this.empty();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Isn't it checking if the field is empty and should go in the else part if something is entered in the input ?

Yes, but think about **when** it does that.

It does it when `empty()` is **called** and you only do that when the document loads.

If you want to run the test again, you need to call the function again. e.g. you might want to [register](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener.) an [`input` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event) listener on the input element.